# Loopback included object

Tags: database, model, include, loopback

I've started using Loopback recently and there's something I don't understand.

I have created models with `lb model` and the connections between them with `lb relation`, no problem.  But when I get the objects from the database, it's impossible to use the model's methods directly on the objects.

For example :

```
BookSub.findOne({where: {"id": bsId}, include: "book"})
.then(bookSub =>{
    bookSub.book.myBookMethod(); 
    // <= Error : Unhandled rejection TypeError: bookSub.book.myBookMethod is not a function
})
```

With :

- BookSub belongsTo Book
- Book hasMany BookSub

To solve this, I'm making a new call to the database, with the book id, but it seems to be a long way to use it.

Did I miss something (are the database objects different from the model objects?) or is it normal? Or do you have some good practices to share on this case?

Answer (score 1):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

This looks like a bug to me. AFAICT from the source code, our intention was to return model class instances, exactly to support the use case you are describing. Can you please create a small app reproducing the problem and open a GitHub issue with the bug report? See [Reporting issues](https://loopback.io/doc/en/contrib/Reporting-issues.html) in our documentation.